# Reset php session to 0 on form submission for Rock, paper, scissors

Tags: php, database, session, post, reset

I've tried numerous things to make this functionality work. I've searched all over stackoverflow to see if there was a solution for the particular issue that I'm having and I'm getting no where. I was wanting to reset the session variable to have the value of 0 when the user hit's the reset button, which is simply just a submit button. I've tried changing it to a get and then setting the if statement to pull from the server to see if the request is GET. I did the same with POST and had no luck. The session just remains and won't destroy at all. It's like it's just neglecting the if statement because I've tried doing a test with an echo statement and get nothing in response. Any ideas of what might be causing the issue? I am populating the session variable then setting it to a variable called `$db_value`. The reason I did that is so that I can write the result to the database and then pull again from the database when the user continues playing.

```
<?php session_start();
    $host = "localhost";
    $user = "username here";
    $pass = "";
    mysql_connect($host, $user, $pass) or die(mysql_error());
    mysql_select_db("RPS") or die(mysql_error());
    mysql_query("SET SQL_SAFE_UPDATES=0;"); // allows updating of table
    mysql_query("Create table if not exists RPS (score int);");
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
    <title>Rock, Paper, scissors</title>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>

<?php
if (isset($_SESSION['Score'])) {
if ($_POST['user_choice']) {
    $user_choice = $_POST['user_choice'];

    $Choosefrom = array(Rock, Paper, Scissors);
    $Choice = rand(0, 2);
    $Computer = $Choosefrom[$Choice];


    //create a variable for the database to use
    $q = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM RPS;");
    $db_array = mysql_fetch_array($q);
    $db_value = $db_array[0];

    if ($user_choice == $Computer) {
        echo 'Result : Draw +0';
        $_SESSION['Score'] = (int) $_SESSION['Score'];
        $db_value = $_SESSION['Score'];
        mysql_query("UPDATE RPS SET score=$db_value;");
    } else if ($user_choice == 'Rock' && $Computer == 'Scissors') {
        echo 'Result : Win +1';
        $_SESSION['Score'] = (int) $_SESSION['Score'] + 1;
        $db_value = $_SESSION['Score'];
        mysql_query("UPDATE RPS SET score=$db_value;");
    } else if ($user_choice == 'Rock' && $Computer == 'Paper') {
        echo 'Result : Lose -1';
        $_SESSION['Score'] = (int) $_SESSION['Score'] - 1;
        $db_value = $_SESSION['Score'];
        mysql_query("UPDATE RPS SET score=$db_value;");
    } else if ($user_choice == 'Scissors' && $Computer == 'Rock') {
        echo 'Result : Lose -1';
        $_SESSION['Score'] = (int) $_SESSION['Score'] - 1;
        $db_value = $_SESSION['Score'];
        mysql_query("UPDATE RPS SET score=$db_value;");
    } else if ($user_choice == 'Scissors' && $Computer == 'Paper') {
        echo 'Result : Win +1';
        $_SESSION['Score'] = (int) $_SESSION['Score'] + 1;
        $db_value = $_SESSION['Score'];
        mysql_query("UPDATE RPS SET score=$db_value;");
    } else if ($user_choice == 'Paper' && $Computer == 'Rock') {
        echo 'Result : Win +1';
        $_SESSION['Score'] = (int) $_SESSION['Score'] + 1;
        $db_value = $_SESSION['Score'];
        mysql_query("UPDATE RPS SET score=$db_value;");
    } else if ($user_choice == 'Paper' && $Computer == 'Scissors') {
        echo 'Result : Lose -1';
        $_SESSION['Score'] = (int) $_SESSION['Score'] - 1;
        $db_value = $_SESSION['Score'];
        mysql_query("UPDATE RPS SET score=$db_value;");
    }

    echo ' You\'re score is currently: ' . $_SESSION['Score'];
    echo '<a href="rps.php">Play Again ?</a>';
    echo '<form method="POST" action="rps.php"><input type="hidden" name="hidden" /><input type="submit" value ="Reset" name="reset" /></form>';
    if ($_POST['reset']) {
        $_SESSION['Score'] = 0;
        $db_value = $_SESSION['Score'];
        unset($_SESSION['Score']);
        session_start();
        session_destroy();
        mysql_query("UPDATE RPS SET score=$db_value;");
        header('Location:rps.php');
    }
} else if (!$_POST['user_choice']) {
    echo 'Your Current Score is: ' . $_SESSION['Score'] . '<form action="rps.php" method="post" />
     <input type="image" src="images/Rock.png" alt="Rock" name="user_choice" value="Rock" title="Rock" height="115" /> <br /><br />
      <input type="image" src="images/Paper.png" alt="Paper" name="user_choice" value="Paper" title="Paper" height="115"/> <br /><br />
       <input type="image" src="images/Scissors.png" alt="Scissors" name="user_choice" value="Scissors" title="Scissors" height="115"/> <br /><br />
   </form> ';
     }
 } else if (!isset($_SESSION['Score'])) {
      $_SESSION['Score'] = 0;

   echo 'Your Current Score is: ' . $_SESSION['Score'] . '<form action="rps.php" method="post" />
  <input type="image" src="images/Rock.png" alt="Rock" name="user_choice" value="Rock" title="Rock" height="115" /> <br /><br />
  <input type="image" src="images/Paper.png" alt="Paper" name="user_choice" value="Paper" title="Paper" height="115"/> <br /><br />
   <input type="image" src="images/Scissors.png" alt="Scissors" name="user_choice" value="Scissors" title="Scissors" height="115"/> <br /><br />
      </form>';
            }
           ?>
             echo'<form method="POST" action="">
             <input type="hidden" name="hidden" />
             <input type="submit" value ="Reset" name="reset" />
            </form>';
             if (isset($_POST['reset']) && ($_POST['reset'] == "Reset")) {
             $_SESSION['Score'] = 0;
            $db_value = $_SESSION['Score'];
           unset($_SESSION['Score']);
            session_start();
          session_destroy();
          mysql_query("UPDATE RPS SET score=$db_value;");
           header('Location:rps.php');
         }
```

Comment: put `session_start()` at the starting of the `PHP` code

Comment: eg: `<?php session_start();`

Comment: I have it there. The session has already been going by this point.

Comment: post the whole php code then.

Comment: I updated the code to reflect exactly what I have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might try $_REQUEST['Reset'] instead of get or post to cover your bases. Use the following sequence at the very top of your code only to destroy a session...

```
$session_id = session_id();

if(empty($session_id)){
 session_start();
}

if(isset($_REQUEST['Reset'])){
 session_unset();
 session_destroy();
 $_SESSION = array();
 session_start();
 session_regenerate_id();
}
```

by and by, your form is way wrong. I doubt you're even getting data from the values here. change it to this:

```
echo ' You\'re score is currently: ' . $_SESSION['Score'];
echo '<form method="POST" action="rps.php"><input type="hidden" name="hidden" /><input type="submit" value ="Play Again" name="Reset" /></form>';
```

...

then on the top of the page do what i put plus a little of yours...

```
$session_id = session_id();

if(empty($session_id)){
 session_start();
}

if(isset($_REQUEST['Reset'])){
 $_SESSION['Score'] = 0;
 $db_value = $_SESSION['Score'];
 session_unset();
 session_destroy();
 $_SESSION = array();
 session_start();
 session_regenerate_id();

 mysql_query("UPDATE RPS SET score = $db_value WHERE unique_field = $unique_field");
 header('Location:rps.php');
 exit;
}
```

where you use this:

```
if ($_POST['reset']) {
```

that will always return true if you write it without a condition. for the value. Plus PHP is case sensitive, so use Reset if you do it how I wrote it.

You're not using XHTML validation, you're using HTML 4.01 Transitional so don't do this:

```
<br />
```

do this:

```
<br>
```

also that goes for the / on your images as well.

Final thought, use a unique value when doing your update, because your statement will change every record in the entire table. See my example with the WHERE clause.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I also had to get rid of the html because that was causing some issues. It resets like it should now. Thanks again.

Comment: glad to help. you might want to consider off-loading your text into variables, then echoing out the variable with static text so you only have to change it in one place. makes it easier to read as well.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry but this is your code rewrited...
(sorry for indent, this wysiwyg editor is very poor and not usefull...)

> <?php
>    //error_reporting(E_ALL);
>    $session_id =
>   session_id();
>
> if(empty($session_id)){
>   session_start();
>    }
>    $DB_Server = "host";
>   //your MySQL Server
>    $DB_Username = "user"; //your
>   MySQL User Name
>    $DB_Password = "pass"; //your MySQL
>   Password
>    $DB_DBName = "db"; //your MySQL Database
>   Name
>    $db = mysql_connect($DB_Server, $DB_Username,
>   $DB_Password);
>    // on sélectionne la base
>    $host =
>   $DB_Server;
>    $user = $DB_Username;
>    $pass =
>   $DB_Password;
>    $db = mysql_connect($host, $user, $pass) or
>   die(mysql_error());
>    mysql_select_db($DB_DBName,$db) or
>   die(mysql_error());
>    //mysql_query("SET
>   SQL_SAFE_UPDATES=0;"); // allows updating of table
>   //mysql_query("Create table if not exists RPS (score
>   int);");
>    /*
>    SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
>    SET
>   SQL_MODE="NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";
>    
>    CREATE
>   TABLE IF NOT EXISTS RPS (
>    score int(11) DEFAULT NULL
>    )
>   ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
>    
>    INSERT INTO RPS
>   (score) VALUES(0);
>    SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1;*/
>
> ?>   <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0
>   Transitional//FR"
>   "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"&gt;   <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"&gt;
>   <head>
>    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type"
>   content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-15" />
>   <title>Rock, Paper, scissors</title>
>    <style
>   type="text/css">
>    .rock {
>   background-image:url(pierre.png);
>    height: 159px;
>   width: 159px;
>    }
>    .paper {
>   background-image:url(feuille.png);
>    height: 159px;
>   width: 159px;
>    }
>    .scissors {
>   background-image:url(ciseaux.png);
>    height: 159px;
>   width: 159px;
>    }
>    </style>
>   </head>
>    <body>
>    <?php
>    if
>   (isset($_SESSION['Score'])) {
>    if (isset($_GET['user_choice']))
>   {
>    $user_choice = $_GET['user_choice'];
>
> $Choosefrom =
>   array('Rock', 'Paper', 'Scissors');
>   srand((double)microtime()*1000000);
>    $Choice = rand(0, 2);   $Computer = $Choosefrom[$Choice];
>
> //create a
>   variable for the database to use
>    $q = mysql_query("SELECT
>   score FROM RPS");
>    $db_array = mysql_fetch_array($q);   $db_value = $db_array[0];
>
> if ($user_choice == $Computer)
>   {
>    echo 'Result : Draw 0';
>    $_SESSION['Score'] = (int)
>   $_SESSION['Score'];
>    $db_value = $_SESSION['Score'];
>   mysql_query("UPDATE RPS SET
>   score='".$db_value."'");
>    } else if
>   ($user_choice == 'Rock' && $Computer == 'Scissors') {
>   echo 'Result : Win +1';
>    $_SESSION['Score'] = (int)
>   $_SESSION['Score'] + 1;
>    $db_value = $_SESSION['Score'];
>  
>   mysql_query("UPDATE RPS SET
>   score='".$db_value."'");
>    } else if
>   ($user_choice == 'Rock' && $Computer == 'Paper') {
>   echo 'Result : Lose -1';
>    $_SESSION['Score'] = (int)
>   $_SESSION['Score'] - 1;
>    $db_value = $_SESSION['Score'];
>  
>   mysql_query("UPDATE RPS SET
>   score='".$db_value."'");
>    } else if
>   ($user_choice == 'Scissors' && $Computer == 'Rock') {
>   echo 'Result : Lose -1';
>    $_SESSION['Score'] = (int)
>   $_SESSION['Score'] - 1;
>    $db_value = $_SESSION['Score'];
>  
>   mysql_query("UPDATE RPS SET
>   score='".$db_value."'");
>    } else if
>   ($user_choice == 'Scissors' && $Computer == 'Paper') {
>   echo 'Result : Win +1';
>    $_SESSION['Score'] = (int)
>   $_SESSION['Score'] + 1;
>    $db_value = $_SESSION['Score'];
>  
>   mysql_query("UPDATE RPS SET
>   score='".$db_value."'");
>    } else if
>   ($user_choice == 'Paper' && $Computer == 'Rock') {
>   echo 'Result : Win +1';
>    $_SESSION['Score'] = (int)
>   $_SESSION['Score'] + 1;
>    $db_value = $_SESSION['Score'];
>  
>   mysql_query("UPDATE RPS SET
>   score='".$db_value."'");
>    } else if
>   ($user_choice == 'Paper' && $Computer == 'Scissors') {
>   echo 'Result : Lose -1';
>    $_SESSION['Score'] = (int)
>   $_SESSION['Score'] - 1;
>    $db_value = $_SESSION['Score'];
>  
>   mysql_query("UPDATE RPS SET
>   score='".$db_value."'");
>    }
>
> echo '
>   You\'re score is currently: ' . $_SESSION['Score'];
>    echo
>   '<form method="GET" action="shifumi.php">   <input type="hidden" name="reset"
>   value="Reset" />
>    <input
>   type="submit" value ="Play Again" />
>   </form>';
>    if ($_GET['reset']) {
>   $_SESSION['Score'] = '0';
>    $db_value = $_SESSION['Score'];   mysql_query("UPDATE RPS SET
>   score='".$db_value."'");
>   unset($_SESSION['Score']);
>    //session_start();
>   session_destroy();
>    if (!headers_sent()){
>   header('Location:shifumi.php');
>    }else{
>    echo
>   '<script
>   language=\"JavaScript\">window.location=\'shifumi.php\';</script>';   }
>    }
>    } else if (!isset($_GET['user_choice'])) {   echo 'Your Current Score is: ' . $_SESSION['Score'] . '<form
>   action="shifumi.php" method="GET" />
>   <input type="hidden" name="user_choice"
>   value="Rock" />
>    <input type="submit"
>   class="rock" value="" alt="Rock"
>   />
>    </form>
>    <br /><br />
>   <form action="shifumi.php" method="GET"
>   />
>    <input type="hidden"
>   name="user_choice" value="Paper" />
>   <input type="submit" class="paper"
>   value="" alt="Paper" />
>   </form>
>    <br /><br />
>    <form
>   action="shifumi.php" method="GET" />
>   <input type="hidden" name="user_choice"
>   value="Scissors" />
>    <input
>   type="submit" class="scissors" value=""
>   alt="Scissors" /> <br /><br />
>   </form> ';
>    }
>    } else if
>   (!isset($_SESSION['Score'])) {
>    $_SESSION['Score'] = '0';
>
> echo 'Your Current Score is: ' . $_SESSION['Score'] . '<form
>   action="shifumi.php" method="GET" />
>   <input type="hidden" name="user_choice"
>   value="Rock" />
>    <input type="submit"
>   class="rock" value="" alt="Rock" />
>   </form>
>    <br /><br />
>    <form
>   action="shifumi.php" method="GET" />
>   <input type="hidden" name="user_choice"
>   value="Paper" />
>    <input
>   type="submit" class="paper" value=""
>   alt="Paper" />
>    </form>
>    <br
>   /><br />
>    <form action="shifumi.php"
>   method="GET" />
>    <input type="hidden"
>   name="user_choice" value="Scissors" />
>   <input type="submit" class="scissors"
>   value="" alt="Scissors" /> <br /><br
>   />
>    </form>';
>    }
>    
>    echo'<form
>   method="GET" action="shifumi.php">
>   <input type="hidden" name="reset"
>   value="Reset" />
>    <input
>   type="submit" value="Reset" />
>   </form>';
>    if (isset($_GET['reset']) &&
>   ($_GET['reset'] == "Reset")) {
>    $_SESSION['Score'] =
>   '0';
>    $db_value = $_SESSION['Score'];
>   mysql_query("UPDATE RPS SET
>   score='".$db_value."'");
>   unset($_SESSION['Score']);
>    //session_start();
>   session_destroy();
>    if (!headers_sent()){
>   header('Location:shifumi.php');
>    }else{
>    echo
>   '<script
>   language=\"JavaScript\">window.location=\'shifumi.php\';</script>';   }
>    
>    }
>
> ?>
>   </body>
>    </html>